# Multiple Jstree ID conflict

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have Two Jstree with two different div

```
<div id="tree1"><div>
<div id="tree2"><div>
```

and i am calling two different json and binding in a tree1 and tree2

and the issue is I have same ID for tree1 li nodes and tree2 li nodes. This cause that only one node is opening and other is hiding.

Eg. If I have opened Tree1 tree and the tree2 tree is hiding because of ID conflict.

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Could you add js code for constructing jstrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the Quick reply I have found the solution

Jstree has solved this issue in their Latest build([3.0.0-beta10](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/releases))

The following sentence is mentioned in their build

> Jstree now allows duplicate IDs on page level (but not in the same
>   tree), basically you can have the same node ID in different trees now

Comment: In HTML though, duplicate IDs in the same document is invalid it seems.  Maybe JSTree should implement something other than directly using the "id" attribute (eg. data-id="123").  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really